# vb6 SSTAB ReSizing controls inside

Tags: vb6

Here is my code.  As soon as I start to create more than 4 tabs the tabs go all over the place and the Listbox height covers the tabs.  How do I fix this?

```
Private Sub Command5_Click()
    Static Xx As Integer
    Xx = Xx + 1
    Text4.Text = Xx
    Dim x As Integer
    Set txt = Me.Controls.Add("VB.listbox", "list3" & Text4.Text, Me)
    Set txt.Container = SSTab1
    For x = 0 To List2.ListCount - 1
    If InStr(List2.List(x), "download") Then
    SSTab1.Tabs = Text4.Text
    SSTab1.Tab = 0
    SSTab1.TabCaption(Text4.Text - 1) = "keywords" & " " & Text4.Text - 1

    txt.Visible = True
    txt.Height = "3855"
    txt.Width = "7575"
    txt.Left = 180
    txt.Top = 480
    txt.AddItem List2.List(x)
    End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: After enough tabs get created, the control adds a second row of tabs.  This decreases the amount of space on each tab.  Since your ListBox is a fixed size, it becomes too big.  You need to calculate the size and position of the ListBox instead of hard-coding values.  And recalculate the size and position of already added ListBoxes.

Answer (score 1):

I created the following helper methods to solve this problem:

```
Private Sub ResizeTabControls()
   Dim c As Control
   Dim lb As ListBox

   For Each c In Me.Controls
      If TypeOf c Is ListBox Then
         Set lb = c

         If InStr(1, lb.Name, "list3") > 0 Then
            lb.Height = TabClientHeight
            lb.Top = TabTabsHeight
         End If
      End If
   Next
End Sub

Private Function TabClientHeight() As Single
   TabClientHeight = SSTab1.Height - TabTabsHeight
End Function

Private Function TabTabsHeight() As Single
   Dim Number As Single
   Dim TabRows As Integer

   'calculate rows rounded up
   Number = SSTab1.Tabs / SSTab1.TabsPerRow

   If Number - Int(Number) = 0 Then
      TabRows = Int(Number)
   Else
      TabRows = Int(Number + 1)
   End If

   'calculate height
   TabTabsHeight = SSTab1.TabHeight * TabRows
End Function
```

With these in place, your existing code looks like this:

```
Private Sub Command5_Click()
   Static Xx As Integer
   Dim x As Integer
   Dim txt As ListBox

   Xx = Xx + 1
   Text4.Text = Xx

   For x = 0 To List2.ListCount - 1
      If InStr(List2.List(x), "download") Then
         SSTab1.Tabs = Text4.Text
         SSTab1.Tab = Text4.Text - 1   'controls get added to the active tab
         SSTab1.TabCaption(Text4.Text - 1) = "keywords" & " " & Text4.Text - 1

         Set txt = Me.Controls.Add("VB.ListBox", "list3" & Text4.Text, Me)
         Set txt.Container = SSTab1
         txt.Visible = True
         'txt.IntegralHeight = False   'can only be set thru the designer
         txt.Height = TabClientHeight  'exact height needs IntegralHeight = False
         txt.Width = 7575
         txt.Left = 180
         txt.Top = TabTabsHeight
         txt.AddItem List2.List(x)
      End If
   Next x

   'resize existing controls whenever a new row of tabs is created
   If SSTab1.Tabs > 1 And SSTab1.Tabs Mod SSTab1.TabsPerRow = 1 Then
      ResizeTabControls
   End If
End Sub
```